# What is the bright object above the moon in Sudbury, Ontario?

Tags: amateur-observing

There is a bright object above the moon in Sudbury, highly visible to the eye, nothing else as bright in the sky except for the moon. I'm looking around 6 and 7am.  What is it ?

Comment: Hi -- since things move in the sky :-),  you should provide the date as well as time of observation.

Answer (score 14):

It's probably the planet Venus. You can use an online planetarium (or one of the many mobile apps) to identify objects. [This link](https://in-the-sky.org/skymap.php?no_cookie=1&latitude=46.49&longitude=-80.99&timezone=-5.00&year=2019&month=1&day=2&hour=6&min=45&PLlimitmag=2&zoom=152&ra=16.04509&dec=-22.22574) shows the sky this morning at 6:45am at your location:

[image]

Comment: What percentage of the time is, *What's the bright object*, Venus? What else could it be? Mars, Jupiter?

Comment: @Mazura: Venus, Jupiter, Mars, Sirius, comet, satellite, rocket plume, airplane, weather balloon, signal flare, drone...

Answer (score 0):

I, too, saw a very bright object in the eastern sky before dawn a few days ago (Saturday-5-Jan-2019).  Based on previous experience viewing astronomical objects, I reckoned that it was probably Venus.  Jupiter would not be that bright unless it were opposite the sun, i.e., closer to us.  Saturn, Mars, and Mercury are NEVER that bright.
With kind regards,
Mark Creek-water Dorazio,  long-time astronomy enthusiast